# Google Mock: "no appropriate default constructor available"?

Tags: c++, constructor, mocking, default-constructor, googlemock

Using Visual Studio 2010 C++ with googlemock.  I'm trying to use a mock I created and I'm getting the compiler error on the line:

```
EmployeeFake employeeStub;
```

The error is:

```
1>c:\someclasstests.cpp(22): error C2512: 'MyNamespace::EmployeeFake' : no appropriate
default constructor available
```

EmployeeFake:

```
class EmployeeFake: public Employee{
 public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetSalary,
      double());
}
```

Employee:

```
class Employee 
{
public:
    Employee(PensionPlan *pensionPlan, const char * fullName);
    virtual ~Employee(void);

    virtual double GetSalary() const;
}
```

I gather that the problem is that the base class doesn't have a default constructor but how should I fix this?  Do I need to add a default constructor to my base class?  Or do I need to add a constructor to my mock class? Or something else?

Comment: You can add a constructor to the derived class that calls the base constructor with suitable parameters, or you can provide default values to the base class's constructor...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Why not post this as an answer since it is ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just add a constructor to your mock that delegates to the Employee constructor:

```
 class MockEmployee : public Employee {
     public:
         MockEmployee(PensionPlan* pension_plan, const char* full_name)
         : Employee(pension_plan, full_name) {}
         // ...
 };
```

Then construct MockEmployee like you would construct Employee. However, there are a couple things that can be improved about this code that I would highly recommend and that would simplify this:

1. Make Employee pure virtual (with a protected default constructor).
2. Rename the current Employee implementation to a name that describes the kind of employee (e.g. FullTimeEmployee or EmployeeWithPensionPlan) and make it inherit from the pure virtual type.
3. Use "virtual ~Employee()" instead of "virtual ~Employee(void)" (using void explicitly in the parameter is a hold over from C and is out of vogue in most C++ communities as far as I'm aware).
4. Use "const string&" instead of "const char*" for the name.

So, to clarify, my recommendation would be:

```
class Employee {
    public:
        virtual ~Employee() {}
        virtual double GetSalary() const = 0;
    protected:
        Employee() {}
};

class FullTimeEmployee : public Employee {
     // your concrete implementation goes here
};

class MockEmployee : public Employee {
    public:
        MockEmployee() {}
        virtual ~MockEmployee() {}
        // ... your mock method goes here ...
};
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if want to deal with passing in a PensionPlan object.  I would think to mock out "GetSalary()" I wouldn't really need a pensionplan object because I'd just be returning a canned response from GetSalary().

Comment: @User, yes, that is why I recommend using a pure virtual Employee base class, with no associated data. Its constructor would not require any parameters at all, since it has to do no initialization. Then make a concrete implementation as well as a mock of that interface.

Comment: I see, I'm reading http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Alternative_to_Mocking_Concrete_Classes which seems to suggest the same thing.  Part of me is wondering about the quick and dirty solution of adding a default constructor to my Employee class.  What do you think?

Comment: So in a unit testing scenario does this mean pretty much every class you want to test needs an interface class and an implementation class (effectively doubling the number of classes)?

Answer (score 2):

You've already suggested a possible answer, but let's spell out some options:

1) Make the base default-constructible. Easiest to do by providing default arguments:

```
explicit Employee(PensionPlan *pensionPlan = 0, const char * fullName = "");
```

(Note that we say `explicit` to avoid tacit conversions from `PensionPlan*`.)

2) Call the constructor in the derived class's constructor's base initializer list:

```
EmployeeFake::EmployeFake() : Employee(0, "") { }
```

2a) Give `EmployeeFake` an appropriate constructor and pass it on:

```
EmployeeFake::EmployeeFake(PensionPlan *p) : Employee(p, "[fake]") { }
```

(Note that (1) is a declaration, while (2) and (2a) are the definitions.)

Comment: I strongly advise against #1; in C++, default parameters really ought to be avoided like the plague. #2 is only an option if that doesn't break the invariants of Employee. Who is to say passing NULL won't make it explode?

Comment: @Michael: If you write a class which can be detonated by calling its constructor, then explosion is certainly a possibility! :-) What's your beef with default arguments, though?

Comment: This does not apply to constructors, but default arguments can have unexpected consequences when attempting to take the address of a function (hey, it worked with this many parameters of these types, why can't I take it's address under that signature?). So it is good to avoid in general (and, by extension, to constructors). Also...

Comment: ...default parameters are bad, especially in large projects, if the default values change and not all compilation units are recompiled, since anything that hasn't been recompiled won't see the new values, and can result in inconsistencies. Forcing the defaults to be in the definition, not the signature, can avoid those sorts of problems.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, the defaults **would** be in the definition, always. Well, I can see your points, but just imagine the standard library without default arguments -- how many explicit hash functors to you want to instantiate? I agree that there should be design guidelines, but I wouldn't be as absolutist as you suggest... :-)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply they are never a good idea (yes, there are places where they are useful), but I would say they should be avoided in most cases (including this one).

Comment: It's strange because none of the googlemock examples I've come across show a constructor in the mock object.  It seems like ideally it'd be unnecessary to have to create a PensionPlan object just to mock a call to "GetSalary()".  But I guess it looks like I just need to appease the compiler by passing *something* to the employee constructor?

Comment: @User: Well, yes, or change the constructor of `Employee` if you never need those values anyway!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Well, I don't need them in the stub/mock version, but the real version does need them.