# C++ : Is it possible to write Mock class for a class with parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am using Google Mock framework to develop unit test cases.
For all the classes that have default constructors, I am able to write a mock class and mock the required methods.
But is it possible for us to write a mock class for a class with no default constructor/ with a constructor but with parameters?

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590178/google-mock-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible for us to write a mock class for a class with no default constructor/ with a constructor but with parameters?

**Definitiely yes!** I have already written such mock classes.

<sub>Do you have particular problems? Then show and make them clear please.</sub>